# Does Opendaylight Carbon support High Availiability deployment of databroker?

Tags: opendaylight

I would like to know that if deploy two ODL platform in High Availability mode which shares same DataBroker is possible or not?

If it is, which path should I follow? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in Carbon. The clustering setup is [fully documented here](http://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-carbon/getting-started-guide/common-features/clustering.html); the short version is:

- install OpenDaylight on all nodes you want to run in the cluster
- on each node in turn, run

  ```
  bin/configure_cluster.sh 2 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3
  ```

  with the node number instead of `2` (so `1` on the first node, `2` on the second node, etc.), and all the nodes’ IP addresses instead of `192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3`;
- start Karaf on each node, and run

  ```
  feature:install odl-mdsal-clustering
  ```

  on each one in turn.